# Dropdown does not show in IE & on mobile devices

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, timepicker

I'm using the https://github.com/Recras/angular-jquery-timepicker to allow time selection in an angular application.It's working well in chrome.
However, in IE the dropdown does not show proper GMT value(ideally it should show plus 5.30 hours).

On mobile device, the dropdown disappears as soon as we touch on it.

Comment: Did you file a bug on github?

Comment: Yes I have reported bug on github.

Comment: @epascarello Can you please help me out ?